# Import spread sheet (OpenOffice) to Visual Basic .net combo box

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, import-from-excel

I have a list of client names, project names, employee names, and hourly rates in an OpenOffice spreadsheet that I need to import to Visual Basic .net 2017. It would be preferred if I could do this to a combo box, so the user can just select the names from a drop-down list. It seems as if this is impossible without setting up an SQL server. Does anyone know how I should go about doing this?

I've tried this but it says that it can't connect to Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0
I got this code from a YouTube video

```
Private Sub btnGetSpread_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetSpread.Click
    Try

        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim dataSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim path As String = "P:\Coding\Visual Studio\Visual Basic\TestProject\TestProject\bin\Files\Company_Sheet.ods"

        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =" + "P:\Coding\Visual Studio\Visual Basic\TestProject\TestProject\bin\Files\Company_Sheet.ods" + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)

        dataSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(dataSet)
        dgvSpread.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)

        MyConnection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Read [ask] and take the [tour] before posting.  Also, several of those tags are mutually exclusive.  The tags include guidance text.

Comment: how is this related to `excel` and to `vba` ?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started.  I sometimes have to import data from Excel spreadsheets into an Oracle database, this code is years old, but still works (VS 2013).  Modify to suit your situation.

```
    Dim sourceFile As String = "C:\Users\appdata\Documents\SomeData.xls"
    Dim srcConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"""
    Dim srcConn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(srcConnString)
    srcConn.Open()
    ' in the select statement, the fields are the column names in the spreadsheet and are expected to be in row 1 and are case sensitive
    ' the from clause in the query is the tab of the spreadsheet where the data is
    Dim cmdExcel As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select NAME,ADDRESS,CITY,STATE,ZIP From [DATA$] Where some where clause", srcConn)
    Dim drExcel As OleDbDataReader = cmdExcel.ExecuteReader()
    ' Now loop through the rows in the spreadsheet
    While drExcel.Read()
        'Do stuff ...
    End While
```